# Unable to build ionic 3 application for ios using Xcode10

Tags: ios, ionic3

I have created a blank ionic project. And I was successfully able to add android platform. But when I am trying to build it on IOS device (XCode 10) it is freezing as shown in the image.

[image].

I ran below command to build the project:

```
ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

I have also tried:

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

But no success.

Any help is recommended. I am stuck on it and is not able to resolve it after referring to various posts.

Answer (score 0):

u could try to do this

```
ionic cordova prepare ios --prod
```

and the make the build direct on xCode